# How to get content of all Elements in an XML using XMLReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I'm using XMLReader to read all Elements in given XML, but contents of some element are not retrieved.

An example:

```
string msg = string.Empty;
using (XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<ns3:Failure xmlns:ns3=\"urn:xxxx\"><Code>Unauthorized</Code><Reason>Access denied</Reason><Detail>Invalid username/password.</Detail></ns3:Failure>")))
{
    while (xReader.Read())
    {
        if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            switch (xReader.Name)
            {
                case "Code":
                    msg = msg + " " + xReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "Reason":
                    msg = msg + " " + xReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "Detail":
                    msg = msg + " " + xReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

After execution of above code, value of msg is " Unauthorized Invalid username/password."
Content of `<Reason>` is missing.
Expected value should be " Unauthorized Access denied Invalid username/password."

How do I get content of all Elements?

Comment: you aren't recursively reading thru the document - you are only reading it once.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, document is read once and then recursively reading each element. The issue is I can get contents of <Code> and <detail> but not of <Reason>

Answer (score 1):

Your `Reason` element is being skipped because after the content of `Code` has been read, the  reader has also moved to the next element (here: `Reason`), which makes the subsequent call to `Read` move to yet one element further (here: `Detail`).

From the documentation of [`ReadElementAsContentString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring?view=netframework-4.6):

> This method reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and
> moves the reader past the end element tag.

There is more than 1 way to solve this.

If you really want to keep the `switch`/`case` check on the element names, you have to make sure to not call the `Read` method when `ReadElementContentAsString` has been called, e.g.:

```
using (XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<ns3:Failure xmlns:ns3=\"urn:xxxx\"><Reason>Access denied</Reason><Code>Unauthorized</Code><Detail>Invalid username/password.</Detail></ns3:Failure>")))
{   
    xReader.MoveToContent();
    while (!xReader.EOF)
    {
        if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            switch (xReader.Name)
            {
                case "Code":
                case "Reason":
                case "Detail":
                    msg = msg + " " + xReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                default:
                    xReader.Read();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            xReader.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, given the example shown in your question, you can just concatenate all nodes of type `XmlNodeType.Text`, e.g.:

```
string msg = string.Empty;
using (XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<ns3:Failure xmlns:ns3=\"urn:xxxx\"><Reason>Access denied</Reason><Code>Unauthorized</Code><Detail>Invalid username/password.</Detail></ns3:Failure>")))
{
    
    while (xReader.Read())
    {       
        if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            msg = msg + " " + xReader.ReadContentAsString();
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot @pfx